# How to use hibernate criteria for selecting only parent table columns and not child table

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

Let say we have two tables: **dept** and **emp**

Now i need to get this query using hibernate criteria:

```
select d. from dept d, emp e
where d.id=e.dept_id
and d.name='HR' and e.age>25;
```

I tried following:

```
     Session session = (Session) getEntityManager().getDelegate();
     Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Dept.class, "d");
     criteria.createAlias("emp", "e");
     criteria.add(Restrictions.like("d.name", name));
     criteria.add(Restrictions.ge("e.age", age));
     List<Dept> results = criteria.list();
```

But this gives me this query output:
         `select d.* ,e.* from` (and not `d.*`)

Any one can help?

Comment: you can set projection by using `setProjection()` method to select columns from `Dept`. So that your query will be `select d.id,d.name from ...`

Comment: The parent table has many columns. There should be a good way of doing this. I couldn't find one but probably there should be one. Projections is ok for selecting a few columns.

Answer (score 0):

By considering `Dept` having properties `id,name`, you can select columns from `Dept` table using `setProjection()`,

```
 Session session = (Session) getEntityManager().getDelegate();
 Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Dept.class, "d");
 criteria.createAlias("emp", "e");
 criteria.setProjection( Projections.projectionList()
    .add( Projections.property("d.id"), "id")
    .add( Projections.property("d.name"), "name"));
 criteria.add(Restrictions.like("d.name", name));
 criteria.add(Restrictions.ge("e.age", age));
 criteria.setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(Dept.class))
 List<Dept> results = criteria.list();
```

**Update**

Or you can use HQL as:

`select d from Dept d inner join d.emp`

So your code will be:

```
String hql = "select d from Dept d inner join d.emp"; // add additional where clause
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
List<Dept> listDepts = query.list();
```

Comment: The parent table has many columns. There should be a good way of doing this. I couldn't find one but probably there should be one. Projections is ok for selecting a few columns.

Comment: @Ankush you can use HQL (as Criteria API uses HQL) in that case, please see update portion of answer

Comment: Yes, i can use HQL, but i was more interested in criteria one. Is there a way we can use criteria. I think performance wise both are same, just criteria is a little neat to understand and gives a good readability.